# NativeScript How to pass Data from service to component?

Tags: angular, promise, nativescript, pass-data

I have a `service` which make an HttpGet method and I want to pass the object that returns from the server to array in `Task component`

I know it is a better approach to use Promise, but I'm not so familiar with it.

So this is what I did so far:

component :

```
userTaskList: Task[ ];

  this.data=this.taskService.getAllTasks()
    this.userTaskList.push(this.data);
```

service :

```
getAllTasks() {
    const req = this.http.get(`${this.serverUrl}/GetTasks`).toPromise().then(
        res => {
        console.log("success" , res);
    });
}
```

I get the object in my log.

```
success [{
JS:   "Id": 27,
JS:   "UserId": 12,
JS:   "Name": "Teeest",
JS:   "Description": "99",
JS:   "Latitude": 0,
JS:   "Longitude": 0,
JS:   "Radius": 99,
JS:   "Created": "2018-08-29T14:01:51.0272032+03:00",
JS:   "LastUpdate": "2018-08-29T14:01:51.0272032+03:00",
JS:   "IsActive": true
JS: }]
```

but how do I take it and send it to the component?
I want to make a list of objects in `userTaskList`.

Thank you !!

Comment: use observables. you can subscribe to updates and do much more with observables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i know its a better approach to use Promise, but i'm not so familiar
>   with it.

No. Not at all. promise does not support , retries , debounces , switchMaps etc.

Not to mention that http requests are auto-completed (rxjs POV)

Anyway  :

Change your code to :

component  :

```
this.taskService.getAllTasks().toPromise().then((data)=> { this.userTaskList =  data});
```

Service :

```
getAllTasks() {
   return  this.http.get(`${this.serverUrl}/GetTasks`) ;
}
```

OR

```
async foo(){

let data = await  this.taskService.getAllTasks().toPromise() ;
this.userTaskList = data

}
```

Service should expose the functionality without invocation.
When you invoke , then you get the value.

BTW - I would've done it with Observable. But I've continued your example.

So I'd use this :

```
 this.taskService.getAllTasks().subscribe((data)=> { this.userTaskList =  data});

 getAllTasks() {
       return  this.http.get(`${this.serverUrl}/GetTasks`) ;
    }
```